# Angular $routeprovider controllerAs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, controllers

I am following the documents as closely as I can but I can not figure out why this isn't working. I was trying to use controllerAs instead of using $parent when I need to get out of the controller, but if I can not figure this out I'm going to have to stick with it.
Route:

```
.when('/user/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
    access: { requiredLogin: true },
    controller: 'UserCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'dr'
```

View:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="dr.formData.last_name">
```

If I remove dr. and do

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="formData.last_name">
```

It works fine.

Edit: as requested here's the controller:

```
angular.module('angularWebappSeedApp')
  .controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope,$routeParams,$http, API_URL) {

    $scope.userId = $routeParams.id;
   $scope.formData = {}; 

   $scope.activeTab = 0;

    var init = function(){
        $http.get(API_URL+'/admin/users/'+$scope.userId).then(function(response) {
            $scope.formData = response.data;
        });
    };

    init();
  });
```

Comment: could you add you controller code too..

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is there any error?

Comment: this looks as though it should function, but does your controller actually have any data?

Comment: @Oleg no the value does not show up in the view unless i remove the dr.

Comment: @Claies yes, if I remove the dr. it works fine.

Comment: well, is `formData` a property on your controller or a property on `$scope`? sounds as though it's a `$scope` value.... we can't really tell you much more without seeing your controller code.

Comment: well there you go, you aren't using the ControllerAs syntax in your controller.

Comment: I think that answers the question then @Claies Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ControllerAs syntax for Angular allows you to avoid directly connecting to `$scope`, by aliasing your controller as a property on `$scope`.

i.e. when using `controllerAs: 'dr'` you will get a property `$scope.dr`.  Inside the controller, you can map your other properties directly to the controller instance, rather than to `$scope`.  For Example:

```
angular.module('angularWebappSeedApp')
  .controller('UserCtrl', function ($routeParams,$http, API_URL) {
    //no need to inject $scope here

    var self = this; //create an alias to avoid closure issues

   self.userId = $routeParams.id;
   self.formData = {};
   ...
```

Now, in your HTML, you can still access these values, even though you never injected `$scope`, because `dr` is a property on `$scope`.

```
ng-model="dr.formData.last_name"
```

Comment: Thank you, there's a lot to think about when learning all the angular stuff, and this detail was lost on me. This helps me understand very much.